# how can I populate inside an array in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to display users that are in a friend group. I am using mongoose and express. This is the friend group schema:

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");

    var FriendGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        public_or_private: { type: String, enum: ["public", "private",] },
        friends: [
            {
                user: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "friend"
                },
                admin: Boolean
            }
        ]
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model("friend_group", FriendGroupSchema);
```

and this is the user schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    profile_picture: String,
    about: String,
    friend_groups: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "friend_group"
        }
    ],
    friends: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "friend"
        }
    ],
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I will need to display the users inside the friend group in a show page of a user. I will need to .populate into the user, then populate into the friend group, and then into the friends array and finally the user and whether he/she is an admin(I will need to display both).
this is what I have so far:

```
.populate({path:"friend_groups", populate: {path: 'friends', populate: {path: 'user', model: 'User'}}})
```

but this doesn't seem to work. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you are defining the ref's right? `ref` should be the name of model you are referring to, in your case there are only two models: `User` and `friend_group` but i don't see `friend` model. I believe that the `ref: 'friend'` should be `ref: 'User'`. But even then, the query is wrong. You should be populating the `friends.user` not `friends` in `path: 'friends'` part.

Comment: @fxgx thank you for your comment. You are absolutely right about the refs, but I have yet an another model called "friend".  Otherwise, your suggestion of populating friends.user proved to be just what I needed.